# Number theory proof mod p

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

For a given prime $p$ and integer $k$,  $k∈<1, p-1>$ $S(k)$ is defined as a sum of remainders of $k, k^2, k^3, ..., k^{p-1}$ when divided by $p$. Prove that $S(k)=\frac{1}{2}p(p-1)$ is true for an odd number of different k.

I managed to prove that $S(p-1)=\frac{1}{2}p(p-1)$ but can't see how to do it further.

Comment: may i ask what you mean by `an odd amount of different k.` ?

Comment: I meant that the amount of k, for which the equation is true, must be an odd number.

Comment: Ah ok interesting.. so when $p=13$, the [sum equals 78](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B12%7D+%28k%5En+mod+13%29+%2C+%7Bk%2C1%2C12%7D%5D) for an odd number of different $k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain what stumps you.)

**Hint:** Prove that $S(k) = \frac{1}{2} p (p-1)$ iff there exists an $a$ such that $ k^a \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

**Corollary:** Hence, if $p -1 = 2^m \times n, $ where $n$ is odd, then the number of solutions is $ (2^m-1) \times n $, which is odd.

---

**Proof of hint without using primitive elements.**

If there exists $ k^ a \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$:
(Proof by algebraic manipulation)  Show that $$ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} ( k^i \pmod{p})   = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (k^i + k^{i+a} \pmod{p} )  = \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} p = (p-1)p. $$
Hence $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (k^i \pmod{p}) = \frac{p-1}{2} \times p$.

If no such $a$ exists, then consider $ v = ord_p (k)$.
(Proof by contradiction) Show that $ v$ is odd, and a factor of $ p-1$.
(Proof by algebraic manipulation) Show that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} ( k^i \pmod{p} = \sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-1}{v}-1} \sum_{i=1}^v (k^{jv + i} \pmod{p} = \frac{p-1}{v} \times \sum_{i=1}^v (x^i \pmod{p}).$$
Observe that if $ p-1 = 2^m \times n$ with $n$ odd, then $ 2^m \mid \frac{p-1}{v} \mid \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (k^i  \pmod{p})$, but $ 2^m \not \mid \frac{1}{2} (p-1)p$, so these 2 values can never be equal.

---

**Hint using primitive elements.** This was originally the easier way to approach. However, now that I've written out the steps which could be followed via algebraic manipulation, you should just review the above.

Consider a primitive element $g$.
Let $ k = g^b$.
Let $ p-1 = 2^m \times n$, where $n$ is odd.
Then $k$ satisfies the conditions iff $ 2^m \not \mid b$.

If $2^m \not \mid b$, then there exists $a$ such that $ ba = \frac{p-1}{2} \times o$, where $o$ is odd. This $a$ satisfies $k^a \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, and the above pairing argument works.

If $ 2^m \mid b$, show that $2^m \mid S(k)$ while $ 2^m \not \mid \frac{1}{2} p (p-1)$, in a similar manner to the above. Hence these terms are not equal.

---

The description of the solution set as powers of $g$ that were not multiples of $2^m$, felt hard to motivate directly. (E.g. how can we tell that if $g^b$ doesn't work, then neither does $g^{2b}, g^{3b}, \ldots$?)

Whereas finding the $k^a \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ condition was quite direct especially after considering small cases. Hence, that was my initial hint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand some parts. I haven't used primitive elements before and I don't really understand what 'g' is here. I also have problems with proving what's in the hint so I'd really appreciate if you could explain it a bit more/give the full solution so I can analyze it.

Comment: @kasper A) A primitive element $g$ is one such that $g^n \equiv 1 $ has no solution for $ n < p-1$. $ Z_p ^\times$ is a cyclic group, and there are $ \phi(p-1)$ such elements. Another way of putting it is that $ \{ g^i \} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots, p-1 \}$. B) I would appreciate if you could explain explicitly what problems you are having in which specific part, and show what you've tried to do to understand that part. I will admit that this writeup does require to put in some work, hence the disclaimer at the start.

Comment: So from what I understand $S(g)$ is always equal to $p(p-1)/2$?

Comment: @kasper I've added an approach that doesn't technically use primitive elements. I've also included numerous steps, which should be almost immediately doable (after some thought). If you get stuck, show your work.

Comment: @kasper Yes, $ S(g) = p(p-1)/2$. However, that's not all of the solution. As you pointed out, $p-1$ is also a solution, but it is not a primitive element (since $(p-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$).

Comment: Is $ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k^i  = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (k^i + k^{i+a} )$ true? Doesn't it mean something like $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k^i  = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (k^{i+a}) $

Comment: @kasper Yes it is true. Recall that $ k^{p-1} \equiv 1 $, and so $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k^i = \sum_{i=1+a}^{p-1+a} k^i = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k^{i+a}$.

Comment: $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k^i = \frac{p-1}{2} \times p$ how can it be true if $S(k)$ isn't equal to $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k^i$?

Comment: @kasper I'm not sure what you're asking. Please clarify by stating your working. We have shown that $S(k) = \sum k^i = (p-1)p/2$.

Comment: Maybe to clarify, it's $ \sum k^i \pmod{p}$ (which is the background that we've been working in), as opposed to $ \sum k^i = (k^p - 1 ) / (k-1)$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $S(n)=\tfrac12p(p-1)$ then also $S(n^{-1})=\tfrac12p(p-1)$, where $n^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $n$ mod $p$. This shows that solutions come in pairs, except those for which $n=n^{-1}$. Of course $n=n^{-1}$ holds only for $n=\pm1$, and a quick check shows that $S(1)=p-1$ and $S(-1)=\tfrac12p(p-1)$.

Comment: +1 That's very nice! I wasn't aware it was a contest-math problem, so I was going for the underlying theory / reasoning.